Why would my quantum resurrection work best in a vacuum?
In my Urban Fantasy setting, Rank 8 Luck Mages have a spell called "Quantum Resurrection." It's supposed to be a form of quantum-based resurrection when the Luck Mage dies. Utilizing the concept of a Boltzmann brain, the spell exponentially increases the probability of quantum fluctuations and virtual particles appearing and arranging themselves in such a way as to create an exact copy of the whole mage before their death, effectively creating a Boltzmann Human. Unlike a regular Boltzmann brain, the Boltzmann Human won't disappear immediately and can operate like a normal human.
This spell works best in a vacuum. Any other conditions and the spell would have a much harder time taking effect.
Why would the quantum resurrection work best in a vacuum? I don't want the explanation to be centered around the magic itself. If possible, I want the answer to be about any specific properties vacuums have that qualifies it or properties of non-vacuum that disqualifies it.

VTC:Needs More Focus. Remember the [help/dont-ask] prohibits open-ended questions. One can sometimes get around this through conditions or an explanation of how the best answer will be judged, making them on-topic finite list of things questions, but with the [tag:magic] tag, anything can legitimately answer the question. (See infinite list of things.) Avoid asking questions like "why?" because we're supposed to be solving specific problems, not philosophizing.

Also, please don't tag your question [tag:magic] and then state you don't want a magic answer, but rather a [tag:science-based] answer. Just tag it [tag:science-based]. Also, remember that our goal is to help you rationalize rules, not crowbar fantasy into the Real World. Cheers.

Since you already tie in quantum mechanics for me the explanation with the best immersion would be "we did our experiements with this and we know that the spell works best in vacuum, but we don't know why, for now we have only some theories and they all have problems. My 73 page long calculations are based on the assumption that the quick movements of particles neccessary for the formation cause to much friction in non-vacuum. But sadly the numbers don't add up to the results we see when acutally using the spell. If I could find the problem that would secure me  the nobel price"

Have the presence of other particles interfere with the process, thereby changing the probabilities of what ever metric is required for this to work. Maybe the presence of other particles creates mutations in the Boltzmann Human.
Some other ways matter can interfere:

The Boltzmann Human could be melded into another object. Matter that is not necessary for the resurrection gets incorporated into the final product.

Too hot and things don't come together. Resurrection fails in a flash of light with E = mc².

Too close and the surroundings incinerate.


Too cold and you get a Bose-Einstein Boltzmann Human Condensate. Now all those particles move in, around, and through each other. Lord knows what could result from that. Maybe that's how the mage can walk through walls.


Whatever you decide, keep the explanation short and devoid of details. Presumably with magic and resurrection, the reader has already suspended belief. Rather than quantum physics being a limitation, find opportunities to weave quantum weirdness into the storyline. You just need a loose connection to some of those concepts. Then the challenge is explaining what a Bose-Einstein Condensate is without taking a crash-course in physics.

There's air in the way
When re-existing, there's no reason for the air that occupies the space to move out of the way on its own, so it's harder for mages to re-exist in non-vacuums. higher level mages can probably achieve it, but it's harder.
Non-empty space is more likely to be observed
(note that i do not have training in quantum mechanics, i'm just stringing along words that seem to make sense.)
Because of the buttefly effect, there is less chance of a mage re-existing in a space where the matter they push away or remove from the space having secondary effects. the secondary effects would be observed, and that would collapse the quantum wave in a state that doesn't result in them re-existing. Since they're luck mages, the more powerful of them could have the ability to make sure the butterfly effects are not observed by "chance", while the weaker of them need to be in vacuum and unobserved directly for it to work.
See also: Quantum immortality
When reading your concept, my mind immediately went to the concept of quantum immortality. Quantum immortality states that for every quantum event that could kill you, there exists a world in which you live, therefore there will always exist a world in which you have survived every quantum event.
If you take this to its extreme and apply literal magic that exists in this context, it's not that far-fetched to consider every event in existence to be quantum, and thus there will always be a world in which the mage has survived (and many many more in which they died, but they're not there to witness them). Why this would work better in a vacuum is, at this point, equivalent to your question about Boltzmann bodies, so the same explanation also applies.
